# SQL Server: getting max purchase value for each individual

Tags: sql-server, max

I have the following query

```
select 
    C.Persona, C.Producto, Sum(C.Cantidad * P.Precio) [Total_Purchase]
from
    Compras C 
join
    Precios P on C.Producto = P.Item
group by 
    C.Producto, C.Persona
```

which returns the total purchase made by each customer (Persona) for each Product.
How can i get it to bring the Max Total Purchase for each customer and the Product involved?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `MAX()` function to do this.  You can add it to your select and it will work, even with `SUM()` being used.

[MAX() Examples](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-maximum-column.html)

Comment: but i don t want the other rows which don t have the max.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you're wanting then.  It sounded like you're pulling back the sum of their purchases, and wanted to see what their largest purchase was in a separate column.  If that's the case, `MAX()` is what you want.  If not, can you try to better explain?

Comment: Let s say within my table, for Thomas i have 3 rows for 3 different products (water, chips, wine) and each ones has the total amount spent on each product in my column Total_Purchase. I have Jerry with also 3 products but different than Thomas, also with the total spent. For this example, i have 6 rows (what my query is bringing) but i want only 2 being Tom's max purchase and what product was it, and the same for Jerry.

Comment: To get back only two rows, you can group by the person and not the product.  So, you can remove `C.Producto` from the `GROUP_BY`.  Once you do that, using `MAX()` in your select will result in what you're wanting.  If you're wanting both, what you have now, and the max for a person as we're talking about here, you'll need to use a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select 
     max(c.[Total_Purchase]), C.Producto ,C.Persona
from 
    (select 
         C.Persona, C.Producto, Sum(C.Cantidad*P.Precio) [Total_Purchase]
     from
         Compras C 
     join
          Precios P on C.Producto = P.Item
     group by 
         C.Producto, C.Persona) c
 group by 
     C.Producto, C.Persona
```

Answer (score 0):

Change SUM aggregate to MAX 
Or include both

```
select C.Persona,C.Producto,
        Sum(C.Cantidad*P.Precio) [Total_Purchase],
        MAX (C.Cantidad*P.Precio) [Total_Purchase
from
Compras C JOIN Precios P ON C.Producto=P.Item
group by C.Producto ,C.Persona
```